# Spring Boot Integration feed sleeps due inactivity

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, spring-integration

I've made a kind of custom Rss Reader using Spring Boot Integration.
It reads my RSS feed every 5 seconds, and if there is a new item, it goes through some filters. If it remains after the filtering, a push notification is sent to my smartphone.

It works great, but if there aren't any new RSS items on my feed for a couple of hours (not sure how long exactly), it doesn't trigger anymore when after these time a new RSS entry appeared.

I assume that my InboundChannelAdapter goes into some kind of `sleep` mode. Does someone know what the exact problem might be?

I have an `InboundChannelAdapter` that reads my RSS feed:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter( value = "feedChannel",
        poller = @Poller(maxMessagesPerPoll = "100", fixedRate = "5000"))
public FeedEntryMessageSource feedAdapter() throws MalformedURLException {
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    return new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL("an url"), "feedChannel");
}
```

I have these `MessageChannel` and `PollerMetaData` beans:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel feedChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(500);
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(10);
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(trigger);
    return pollerMetadata;
}
```

And an `MessageEndpoint` that receives the RSS notifications:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public static class Endpoint {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private PushbulletConfig pushbulletConfig = new PushbulletConfig();

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "feedChannel")
    public void log(Message<SyndEntry> message) throws Exception {
        SyndEntry payload = message.getPayload();
        //Do something with payload
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but the .jar is deployed in a `docker` container using the `se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2` `gradle` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `@Poller` on the `@InboundChannelAdapter` you don't need `PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER`. If you don't have other polling consumers, of course, without their own Poller config.
2. Try to use `fixedDelay` instead of `fixedRate`. The last does this logic:

   ```
   else if (this.fixedRate) {
       return new Date(triggerContext.lastScheduledExecutionTime().getTime() + this.period);
   }
   return new Date(triggerContext.lastCompletionTime().getTime() + this.period);
   ```

   Therefore several Threads may be busy. Especially when `feed = this.feedFetcher.retrieveFeed(this.feedUrl);` responds enough slow.
3. Configure `DEBUG` log level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and come back to us with some logs on the matter!

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and check if the problem is fixed. If not I'll update my post with logs.

Comment: The `PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER` was used by the `@ServiceActivator endpoint by the way, but I removed it and gave it a Poller using `@Poller` with the same settings as the one I gave to the `@InboundChannelAdapter`. Not sure if it would be better to define one and share it between the two.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Now I see that your `feedChannel` is a `QueueChannel`. That doesn't not make so much sense in case of polling adapter as a start. From other side your `fixedRate` with `10ms` is very dangerous just for 10 Threads in the default `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: It seems like the problem is fixed now. Thanks a lot!